# Cortex-M external interrupt occurs when executing fault handler with higher priority

Tags: arm, embedded, interrupt, cortex-m

What happens when a lower priority interrupt from a peripheral occurs while the cortex-m is executing a higher priority fault handler? Will it be ignored or will it trigger a hardfault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a higher priority interrupt is being serviced, the lower-priority interrupt will remain pending. Once the higher priority ISR completes, the lower-priority interrupt will be serviced. Multiple interrupts can be in the pending state waiting to be handled. They will be handled in order of their priority.

In addition, Cortex-M CPUs have a feature called tail-chaining. This means that when the higher-priority ISR completes, it does not need to pop all the saved registers from the stack, only for them to get pushed again when the low-priority ISR gets run. Instead, the lower-priority ISR gets called directly, then when it exits, it will pop the saved registers.

Comment: If more than one low-priority interrupt arrives at this point, only one will eventually be handled? Or will it be like a "queue", and if so how long can the "queue" be?

Comment: More than one can be "queued". There is no limit other than how many interrupts the CPU supports. They could all be pending, in theory. I've edited the answer to that effect.